# Iterate Shape children - Flash/as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am using Flash CC.
I have drawn 7 rectangles using the Rectangle Tool.
I then converted the 7 as one movie clip (By hitting F8).

The Problem:
I want to be able to iterate through these shapes and move each individually.
However the 7 rectangles seem to be encapsulated into the ONE shape and I can't access them.?
If I use .numChildren on the movie clip, it returns 1.
If I use .getChildAt("anything > 0") its a null reference exception.

Please help, 
I don't understand how this is so difficult.

I have searched for ages to find the solution to this and for the life of me I can't.
Thanks in advance.

(P.s) Instantiating the rectangles in code works, but I need to be able to do this via Flash CC as I will be importing artist material for manipulation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best choice is to make every shape in your made movie clip a movie clip as well.
In Flash go into your made MovieClip (I will call it containerMC for easier understanding) and make every shape a MovieClip by hitting F8. You can also give them instance names, if you want, just make sure they're unique.

Then your containerMC will return numChildren value 7 in your case.
You can move/access your shapes in the containerMC via getChildAt(), or by using their instance names that you've provided via containerMC.instance1 or containerMC["instance1"].

Comment: This may be the answer I was looking for,,, I'm not at work any more so I will check this out in the morning..
I assume that some sort of batching process is going on to optimize/support all the graphics on screen?
Do you think that this will impact on performance if i convert all these to movie clips?
Thanks again!

Comment: There will be no noticeable performance difference, since making it a movieClip will add only few hundred bytes (even less if you make it a Sprite, if it doesn't have animation but want to maintain interactivity). Flash does a bad job at optimizing things, so in the end you still need to test it, but I don't see how it would be a bottle neck. It's more about how you handle the graphics, in the end you could just make them Bitmaps or use copyPixels() to achieve max performance. If you want to use GPU for rendering, you'll probably need to use Starling anyway.

Comment: On second thoughts, this probably won't work as I'm only going to be able to change all those Shapes in code to movie clips as in the project i am working on, there is going to be literally hundreds, if not more...

Comment: In this case you need a different approach. In code make a Sprite, it will be your shape holder/container. Then in code make as many shapes as you want and add them to the container via addChild(). Upon creating the shapes add them to an array to be able to reference them for later use. Then it doesn't matter how many you have as long as Flash doesn't run out of memory ;)